# Am I using selectors incorrectly in this CSS? Having issues getting h2 to change colors

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, css-selectors

I'm horrible with CSS and selectors.  Is it possible to figure out what I could possibly use as CSS to accomplish my objective?

Specifically, I'd like Audrey Edmunds to be bold and yellow, but no matter what I try, I just can't seem to make it work.

[image: Audrey Edmunds]

No matter what I try, however, the person's name still shows up as almost transparent, unless you hover over it (just above the description), then it's light blue.

Here's the current CSS I'm using on [the page I'm having issues with](http://www.occupyhln.org/exonerated-from-prison-and-death-row/):

```
.slideshow_container { background: #000; }

.slideshow_container a { color: white; text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; text-decoration: 
none; }

.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide { margin-right: 2px; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_text h2 { color: white; text-align: left; font-size: 
1.3em; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_text p { color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: 
left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_image { }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_video { }

.slideshow_container .slideshow_description { background: #000; width: 100%; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description h2  { color: white; font-size: 1.3em; 
text-align: left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description p  { color: #FFFF00; font-size: 1.1 em; 
font-weight: bold; text-align: left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description a  { color: #FFFF00; font-size: 1.1 em; 
font-weight: bold; text-align: left; }
```

Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working the way you want you can do this:

```
.slideshow_description.slideshow_transparent h2 a {
    color: #FFFF00 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

or this one that's even better because it doesn't use `!important`:

```
#content .slideshow_description.slideshow_transparent h2 a
{
    color: yelllow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Leniel.  I really need to take a CSS class.  I always forget the !important ... Thanks a bunch or taking the time to help!

Comment: `CSS` is all about selector precedence and where you place the `CSS` rule in your stylesheet... :) You're welcome!